# List of assets on Statemint

Tags: polkadot-js, assets, python, statemint

How do I get the list of all the assets that are present and their supply in Statemint?

Ideally either with Polkadot-JS api or py-substrate-interface.

Answer (score 3):

Using PolkadotJS you can get the list of assets with this script:

```js
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://statemint.api.onfinality.io/public-ws');
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

    const chain = await api.rpc.system.chain();
    console.log(`----- Chain: ${chain} -----`);

    const assets = await api.query.assets.metadata.entries();
    assets.forEach(([{args: [id] } ,asset]) => {
      console.log(`${id}: ${asset}`);
      });
```

You can also query the list of assets using PolkadotJS UI calling the extrinsic metadata and disabling *Include Option*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using py-substrate-interface it would be something like:

```python
substrate = SubstrateInterface(url="wss://statemint-rpc.polkadot.io")

assets_metadata = substrate.query_map(
    'Assets', 'Metadata'
)

for asset, metadata in assets_metadata:
    print(f'Metadata of asset "{asset.value}": {metadata.value})')
```

- You can find Python usage examples for other call- and storage functions here: https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-metadata-docs/statemint/#metadata
- More info about `query_map()`: https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#query-a-mapped-storage-function